# Ошибка в акцессе can't find dll entry point при создании dll

Tags: c#, dll, access

пишу dll на c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TextToMDB
{
    public class TextToMDB
    {
       private static  bool chekComa(string arg)
        {
            if (arg.IndexOf(",")>0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }

    }
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public static void RemoveTab()
    {
        string text = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\Мои документы\333.txt");
        if ( chekComa(text))
        {
            text = text.Replace("\t",",");
            File.WriteAllText(@"c:\Мои документы\333.txt", text);
        }
    }
}
```

}

добавляю ссылку [image: в акцессе]

плюс добавляю 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но к методу достучаться из кода vba не могу, при обращении к `RemoveTab` получаю сообщение

> can't find dll entry point

Comment: Не знаю умеет ли c# экспортировать функции как найтивные, если и умеет то вам надо доставить ещё атрибутов (флагов). Атрибут **ComVisible** говорит о том что вы функцию будете использовать через ActiveX, т.е. посредством `set myObj = CreateObject("Ваш класс")` и `myObj.RemoveTab` а в такой способ нельзя. Класс нужно дополнительно регистрировать в системе (правила публикуемых COM обьектов).

Comment: Попробуйте добавить атрибут  [System.Reflection.Obfuscation(Feature = "DllExport")] (взято из http://jonxxx.me/13-metatrader/15-eksport-funktsij-iz-net-dll-c-dllexport-net-framework-v-metatrader)

Comment: Вот пошаговое руководство как сделать экспортируемый COM. Как вызвать написано выше. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12673/Calling-Managed-NET-C-COM-Objects-from-Unmanaged-C

Comment: А почему эти две процедуры нельзя написать на vba? Первая ф-ция **InStr** https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/47d6yh63.aspx Вторая CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"), OpenTextFile ReadAll и т.д. http://www.script-coding.com/WSH/FileSystemObject.html

Answer (score 1):

Приведу пример одной процедуры по просьбам на с++ можно перевести и другую процедуру. Она переводится но с ней чуть больше мороки. Если вы всю задачу изложили, я предлагаю вам переписать это всё на с++. В первой процедуре нужно "угадать аргумент" - это единственная загвоздка. Он может быть `wchar_t*`, `VARIANT*`, `VARIANT`. Скорее всего первое.

```
   extern "C" _export bool chekComa(wchar_t* arg); // в некоторых языках лучше добавить для "простого" имени.
   _export bool chekComa(wchar_t* arg)
    {
      while (*arg!=0) if (*arg++ == ',') return true;
      return false;
}
```

По вашей просьбе вторую процедуру вам тоже переведут на с++.
Второй вариант, а почему бы вам не написать всё на VBA?

```
 function  chekComa(string arg) as Bool 
 Begin
   if instr(arg,",") = 0 then begin
       chekComa = false
   end else begin
       chekComa = true
   end
 end function

sub RemoveTab()
  dim fso, f, d
  set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  set f = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\Мои документы\333.txt")
  d = f.ReadAll
  d = Replace(d, chr(8), ",")
  f.Close
  set f = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\Мои документы\333.txt",2)
  f.Write(d)
  f.Close
end sub
```

Писал без проверки в коде могут быть неточности.