# как на c# написать dll для access

Tags: c#, dll, com

как на c# написать dll для access, хорошо бы работающий пример. Я пробовал сделать--моя dll подключается, но при ее вызове в коде access выскакивает ошибка  - ожидается точка входа(can't find dll entry point).

Comment: Насколько сложная у вас программа? Может проще на с++ вам написать?

Comment: Приведите ваш пример кода ( хотя бы основной класс, который вызывается из dll, чтобы понять где ошибка).

Comment: @alexoander вот ошибка http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/580148/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5-cant-find-dll-entry-point-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-dll дело в том что access предполагает native библиотеку, а c# делает только CLR библиотеку

Comment: Если ваша программа простая, напишите её на c++, если сложная вы можете 1. Создать COM обьект http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12673/Calling-Managed-NET-C-COM-Objects-from-Unmanaged-C 2. На с++ написать шлюз на c# сделав мост access - c++ - c#. 3. Освоить костыли позволяющие с c# скомпоновать native х86 код.

Comment: 4. Ваш ассеss связывается с sql-сервером? sql-сервер умеет подключать c#. Вариант 5. пишите c# console запускаете exe-файл с# сделав redirect консоли, и закачивате выдаваемые данные в access. 6. создаёте "службу" и делаете обмен через named pipe (как бы виртуальный файл, работа с ним похожа на сокет).

Comment: @nick_n_a Вы же потом оформите ответ?

Comment: @4per я считаю что всё что я изложил не является ответом, ответ должен быть с примерами. пункт 1,2,3,4 я никогда не пробовал. Если вы уверены что знаете ответ - напишите. Советы что можно делать которые не помогли автору я не считаю ответом.

Comment: @nick_n_a --Ваш ассеss связывается с sql-сервером?--это сложный путь связывается--и вообще если не получится dll - считаю данные как есть а на серваке разделаю их под орех как мне надо. Но мне хочется очень dll на си шарпе--это не есть конечно правильный путь--но тем не менее тогда я буду богом в нашем проекте.

Comment: По описаниям в нете, для того что бы собрать на с# библиотеку с опубликоваными native функциями - нужно имень лицензию на VS 2015 и установить какой-то плагин. А вообще я думаю что это нонсенс что с# 2015 не может связаться с свеженьким там Access 2014 именно таким образом. Я думаю, эту проблему должна решить сама Microsoft в свежей версии Access. Я думаю надо подождать, и может даже написать им жалобу (если вы лицензионный пользователь)))), в sql они интеграцию сделали - и в VBA тоже должны сделать. Можете попробовать костыли из п3.

Answer (score 1):

Создаем проект dll например ClassLibrary1 в Visual Studio 2015.

В свойствах проекта, в Build нужно выставить параметр `Platform` и `Register for COM interop`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выставить платформу нужно для того что бы указать тулзе-регистратору, какой COM регистрировать x86 или x64. Я тестировал с MS Office x64, так что пришлось в обязательном порядке выставить платформу.

Также нужно обратить внимание, что в этом случае Visual Studio пытается зарегистрировать COM объект, а это значит, что она должна быть запущена от имени администратора.

Пишем класс в C#:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class Class1
    {
        public string GenerateMessage()
        {
            return "Hello, World!";
        }
    }
}
```

Тестируем его в VBA:

```
Private Sub ShowMessage()
    Dim o1 As Object
    Set o1 = CreateObject("ClassLibrary1.Class1")

    Dim msg As String
    msg = o1.GenerateMessage()

    MsgBox msg

    Set o1 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: все это делал - получал .dll и .tpl, делал ссылку на tpl файл из акцесса и получал неизменное can't find dll entry point

Comment: если не поставить указанную Вами галку - мы не получим tpl файл в сборке.

Comment: Ты с .NET библиотекой работаешь как с COM или как с `c (си)` dll?

Comment: #MaLS я не очень понял суть Вашего вопроса, но наверное как с COM. Access работает с com по всей вероятности...

Comment: Я вышел из положения средствами Access -распарсил файл и дополнил строки нужными мне символами--но тем не менее - вопрос остается открытым! КАК НАПИСАТЬ dll на c# для Access! Самый простецкий работающий вариант есть у кого?

Comment: Самый простой я описал. Куда уж проще?