# Использование .NET DLL в Office

Tags: .net, com, office

Возникло несколько вопросов по работе с либами .NET через office(VBA):

1. На основании чего выбирать разрядность либы? На основании разрядности Office или ОС?
2. Можно ли скомпилировать либу, как AnyCpu и не ломать себе голову с первым пунктом?
3. Смысл regasm в том, что бы просто либа была видна в референсах, т.е можно обойтись без этого шага и просто указать к ней путь в VBA Офиса?

Answer (score 1):

На ваши вопросы нельзя ответить напрямую, так как в них не учитывается основной момент - это технология COM.

Из VBA можно работать с библиотеками, которые реализуют спецификации COM объектов и нельзя напрямую работать с .NET объектами. Таким образом, библиотеке .NET требуется реализовать спецификации COM, чтобы его функционал можно было задействовать из VBA.

> На основании чего выбирать разрядность либы? На основании разрядности Office или ОС?

Разрядность выбирается на основании разрядности процесса, в котором будет запущен COM объект. Дело в том, что COM объекты могут быть In-Proc или Out-Proc, т.е. запускающиеся в процессе вызывающего или в отдельном.

> Можно ли скомпилировать либу, как AnyCpu и не ломать себе голову с первым пунктом?

Можно, но нужно помнить про правильный маршалинг данных.

> Смысл regasm в том, что бы просто либа была видна в референсах, т.е можно обойтись без этого шага и просто указать к ней путь в VBA Офиса?

VBA видит COM объекты, которые прописываются в реестре Windows согласно спецификации COM. `regasm` нужен для того, чтобы прописать данные по функционалу .NET библиотеки в реестре согласно спецификации COM. Но его можно не использовать постоянно, если выставить галочку в `Register for COM interop` в свойствах проекта, см. [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/580537/11230).

Comment: Т.е regasm нужен, что бы видеть либу в списке либ офиса, однако имея tpl файл, я могу ручками добавить либу в этот список?

Comment: @iluxa1810 regasm нужен для того, чтобы библиотеку .NETвнедрить в систему Windows как COM библиотеку.